# Usefulness of Publish the Value Zero for cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

According to [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html) I should consider publishing value zero instead of no data because I "can set a CloudWatch alarm to notify you if your application fails to publish metrics every five minute".

But I can set a cloudwatch alarm to notify on INSUFFICIENT_DATA too. Is using 0 a more reliable way of doing this? Is using 0 over INSUFFICIENT_DATA recommended by amazon because its more reliable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an alarm via either method.

However, there is a difference between publishing a value of zero and an alarm state of INSUFFICIENT_DATA.

If your service is running, then publish a zero value instead of not publishing and having the alarm go into the INSUFFICIENT_DATA state. In the first case you know your service is running. In the second case you have no data. This may or not be valuable to you but at least your log files will not have missing time areas.